# Transfer EC2 and s3 ownership to another user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm currently managing the AWS account of my company. Soon I'll be moving out of the organization and I want to transfer the account to a colleague here. The billing information and the rest are still the same.

I know I can backup the image and set up a new account, but that's a drag. Is there a simple way to transfer the ownership like in heroku?

Answer (score 2):

> The billing information and the rest are still the same.

Billing privileges are available to AWS root account only. If you are talking about root account, then just hand over the credential to you peer.

> I want to transfer the account to a colleague here

What do you mean by transfer? If this is not a root account and is an IAM account, then I would say just create an IAM account with full Admin privileges for your peer and then delete your own account.

> I can backup the image and set up a new account

I don't think I understand what do you mean by above statement.

Comment: This is a good answer, I just want to clarify that it is now possible to give IAM users [access to billing information](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/ControllingAccessWebsite.html).